# Help with signature and seal

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

I have a painting with this signature and seal, can anyone tell me anything about it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: 鶴]

The seal characters are 「⿱黍日（香）鶴」, which literally translate to *fragrant [crane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_(bird))*. This is either an [art name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_name) (a professional pseudonym used by Chinese and other East Asian artists) or is referring to the artwork itself.

The cursive calligraphy above the seal *possibly* refers to the same characters, but they look like they were written in a non-standard way to me.

---

##### Notes on seal character identification of 「香」

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[續](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)3.28.5
[合集36501](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=36501&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
伯㺇簋
[考古](https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E8%80%83%E5%8F%A4%E8%88%87%E6%96%87%E7%89%A9)06.6</kbd>
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image: ⿱黍甘]
[香部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=111)
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd><kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image: 香]
史晨碑</kbd>
　
<kbd>[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image: 香]</kbd>

「香」 was originally written as 「⿱黍口」, comprised of semantic [「黍」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=2922) (a variety of high-grade *millet* used in glutinous grain and alcohol production) and an ideographic mark [「口」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=39) used to distinguish the character 「⿱黍口」 from 「黍」.

Later on, 「口」 was complexified into various similar-looking shapes to [「甘」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=264) and 「日」; the modern form inherits the shape of 「日」. 「黍」 was also later simplified to [「禾」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=281).

Comment: It's exactly the seal's meaning, but the signature is not 香鹤, I think.